# Springboot put method is not working (Console shows a get call)

Tags: java, spring-boot

I want to add a name to my `strings` ArrayList, but when I'm calling the put- method the console.log shows a get method.

When I'm calling the url `http://localhost:8081/strings/add/Test` I got

```
Whitelabel Error Page
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Fri Oct 22 10:49:01 CEST 2021
There was an unexpected error (type=Method Not Allowed, status=405).
Request method 'GET' not supported
```

On the console I can see this
[image]

But it should be a put method and not a get method, what is wrong?

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.DeleteMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PutMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class BasicController {

    private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(BasicController.class);
    ArrayList<String> basicList = new ArrayList<String>();


    @GetMapping("/strings/get")
    @ResponseBody
    public String getAllStrings() {
        return basicList.toString();
    }


    @PutMapping("/strings/add/{newString}")
    @ResponseBody
    public String addNewString(@PathVariable String newString) {
        logger.debug(newString);
        basicList.add(newString);
        return newString + " added";
    }
    

}
```

Main

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@SpringBootApplication
@RestController
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String hello() {
        return "Hello World!";
    }

}
```

Springboot I'm using `2.5.6`

Comment: You have a typo. The right URL (according to your controller) would be : `http://localhost:8081/strings/put/Test`

Comment: @Renis1235 thank you, but that was not the problem. It occurs also with the url `http://localhost:8081/strings/put/Test`

Comment: Probably the problem is how you are doing the call to that url, could you explain how you are doing it please?

Comment: You have to do a PUT request and not a GET for the call to work correctly. use `cURL` or Postman for that

Comment: @Billy I'm calling this url `http://localhost:8081/strings/add/Test` (Yes, I changed the url in the method :D, sorry for that).

Comment: @Renis1235 and how ? :/

Comment: We need to know how you are doing this call, opening the url in a web browser? Using a program like Postman or Insomnia?

Comment: @Billy I don't know. I just downloaded the spring initializr and I run the Main

Comment: https://learning.postman.com/docs/getting-started/sending-the-first-request/ this should help.

Comment: And I run this in a normal browser.

Comment: When I'm calling this inside of Postman it works. But not in the browser :/

Comment: A browser always makes a GET call through the URL Bar. POST/ PATCH/ PUT/ DELETE are to be done through Apps/ other services.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are running the call in a browser, by default this will trigger a get request instead of a put, please check this documentation to learn about Http methods
[Http Methods explanation](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp#:%7E:text=GET%20is%20used%20to%20request%20data%20from%20a,data%20to%20a%20server%20to%20create%2Fupdate%20a%20resource.)

As you pointed out in one of your comments, you are gonna need Postman or other similar tools to make it work properly.